# Hide keyboard when user touches fragment inside activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, keyboard

Inside the .xml layout I have 3 components in following order:

- A Textview
- A fragment (extends ListFragment)
- A LinearLayout storing 2 buttons

Whenever user uses the search bar to query, the keyboard appears. Content of the fragment will be updated depending on the query.

**What I'm trying to do** is whenever user taps the screen (outside the keyboard), **the keyboard needs to be hidden**. So far, I could only do so if I tap anywhere **but the fragment region**.

I tried `setOnTouchListener` inside `onActivityCreated()` inside the fragment but it doesnt seem to work.

I got tapping outside the fragment = hidding keyboard to work by using the following inside `onCreate()`:

```
layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent ev)
   {
      hideKeyboard(view);
      return false;
   }
});
```

hideKeyboard(View view)

```
public void hideKeyboard(View view)
    {
        InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
```

But not inside the fragment...

Answer (score 0):

I made a silly mistake....

The following code would solve the issue:
Inside `onActivityCreated()`

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mid).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View dview, MotionEvent ev)
            {
                f_hideKeyboard(dview);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

---

Edited: Nevermind.... The above works only if the query shows zero result. If it shows at least 1 result, touching the fragment region still will not hide keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's a bit late. From what I have understand from your question, here is the solution below. Use the following code inside onCreateView

```
//hides keyboard when tap on the screen
    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                //do something
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```